# Proof of equation (3) Lemma 3.5 Do Carmo's Riemmenian Geometry.

Tags: proof-verification, differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry

Related to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3313605/gauss-lemma-in-do-carmos-riemmenian-geometry-why-the-curves-ft-s-exp-p-tv?noredirect=1#comment6817431_3313605), which has a reference to the statement of the lemma in the subject of this question.

I'm trying to work out by myself the details of equation (3) of the book.

$$
\left\langle \frac{\partial f}{\partial s}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \right\rangle(1,0) = \left\langle d (\exp_p)_v(w_N), d (\exp_p)_v(v) \right\rangle
$$

Although it has been answered already in one of the linked questions I've been trying to add more details just as an exercise. Also mostly because I want to make sure I understand the notation used by author.

For sake of making things a bit shorter I'll use the notation

$$
\begin{array}{l}
\partial_s f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial s} = df_{(t,s)} \left( \partial_s\right)\\
\partial_t f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} = df_{(t,s)} \left( \partial_t\right)
\end{array}
$$

Since

$$
f : (t,s) \to \exp_p(tv(s))
$$

where $v(s)$ is a curve in $T_p \mathcal{M}$ such that $v(0) = v$ and $v'(0) = w_N$ we have

$$
\partial_s f = df_{(t,s)} \left( \partial_s \right) = d (\exp_p)_{(t,s)} \left( \partial_s \right)
$$
$$
\partial_t f = df_{(t,s)} \left( \partial_s \right) = d (\exp_p)_{(t,s)} \left( \partial_t \right)
$$

Therefore

$$
\left\langle \partial_s f , \partial_t f\right\rangle(1,0) = \left\langle d (\exp_p)_{(t,s)} \left( \partial_s \right), d (\exp_p)_{(t,s)} \left( \partial_t \right) \right\rangle(1,0) \;\;\; (1)
$$

Is my derivation of (1) correct? Assuming it is...

I think the difficult bit is to compute $d (\exp_p)_{(t,s)}$, my attempt is the following

$$
d (\exp_p)_{(t,s)} = d (\exp_p)_{tv(s))} d (tv(s))_{(t,s)} \;\;\;\; (2)
$$

I'll know compute $d (tv(s))_{(t,s)}$. Since $v : s \to T_p \mathcal{M}$ it means it can be written as

$$
tv(s) = \sum_{i=1}^n t v_i(s) \partial_{x_i} = t v_i (s) \partial_{x_i}
$$
Since the differential of the map is the Jacobian of the coordinates transformation we have

$$
d(tv(s))_{(t,s)} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1(s) & tv_1'(s) \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
v_n(s) & tv_n'(s)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

If I substitute $(t,s) = (1,0)$ I get

$$
d ( \exp_p )_{tv(s)} = d ( \exp_p )_{v(0)} = d ( \exp_p )_{v}
$$
$$
d ( tv(s))_{(t,s)} = \begin{pmatrix}
v_1(s) & tv_1'(s) \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
v_n(s) & tv_n'(s)
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
v_1(0) & v_1'(0) \\
\vdots & \vdots \\
v_n(0) & v_n'(0)
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Observe in the matrix above the first column represents the coordinates of $v$ while the second column represents the coordiantes of $w_N$. Plugging $\partial_s$ would provide me the second column, while $\partial_t$ would provide me the first, plugging everything together I get the equation (3) of the book.

There few details I'm omitting but I think the idea is clear, I also hope I haven't done any mistakes with rows and columns in the computation of the differential map.